# Django Admin Queryset Method Override; Poorly Performing Query

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a system with multiple Sites in it. Every User object in the system gets a Profile object attached to it which governs which Sites they have permission to interact with. The system also has an Article model which can belong to multiple sites. So, when a user loads up the Article admin page, I only want them to see Articles that are assigned to sites they have access to see. So, I override the queryset method on the Article's Admin class with something like this:

```
qs = model.objects.filter(sites__id__in=[x.id for x in user.get_profile().group_profile.allowed_sites.all()]).distinct()
```

Taking the user, getting the Sites they have access to, and pulling Articles whose site assignment is in that list. Problem is, this query becomes a real dog once you get up to a few hundred thousand articles and is exacerbated by the model itself being large, meaning that Django is pulling a lot of data and running a DISTINCT on a large column list.

I'm looking for ways to improve it but the queryset method doesn't seem to give me much of an out. I originally tried using the QuerySet function only() to pull only columns I need to draw the changelist, but then found that that caused post_save signals for the model not to fire when saved. I can't get rid of the distinct, because if I do, I'll get multiple results per site: i.e., if user can see Site A and Site B, and an Article belongs to both sites, the query would return the Article twice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a ManyToMany relationship you can't get rid off the `distinct()` because there have to be multiple joins done for every instance. Something you can do about your query (though I don't think that this will be some big performance boost), you don't have to do the '__in' querying with the ids:

```
qs = model.objects.filter(\
        sites__in=user.get_profile().group_profile.allowed_sites.all()).distinct()
```

Comment: As you said, this doesn't really affect the speed. The allowed_sites is a short list from a small (15 max) table. It's the distinct that's really killing it, or at least that way that Django seems to be forcing me to pull every column in the model, making the distinct() comparison brutal.

Comment: can this be what you are looking for?
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.queryset